# Spring Boot Custom ContextLoaderListener

Tags: resteasy, spring-boot

I am trying to use RestEasy with Spring Boot. I need to configure it so it uses RestEasy's SpringContextLoaderListener instead of the Spring Boot default. I tried adding the listener in the config class but I get an error saying that a Context Loader Listener already exists.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this other one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720400/how-configure-spring-boot-app-to-continue-to-use-resteasy/39114485#39114485

Comment: @Fabio, yes the ticket you linked was created almost a year after this one. Since the time this question was posted the starter you mentioned in the answer to the question was created and is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use RESTEasy's `SpringContextLoaderListener`, you should be able to get this to work by dependency on `org.jboss.resteasy:rest easy-spring` and importing its `springmvc-resteasy.xml` configuration:

```java
package sample.resteasy;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
@ImportResource("classpath:springmvc-resteasy.xml")
public class SampleResteasyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleResteasyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Note that `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` has been disabled. This is to work around a [problem with RESTEasy's `SpringBeanProcessor`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/pull/578) that causes a failure when it encounters a non-public `@Bean` method. `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` declares such a method so, to get RESTEasy to work, it has to be disabled.