# How to integrate Spring Boot and Resteay

Tags: spring-boot, resteasy

Although there are a lot of code example on the internet of integrating Spring Boot/Spring and Resteasy, but most of them are out of data or even don't work.

I am look at the latest Resteasy document, try to create a instance of SpringBeanProcessorServletAware in my config bean.

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ResteasyBootstrap> resteasyBootstrapRegistratio() {
    ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ResteasyBootstrap> registration = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
    registration.setListener(new ResteasyBootstrap());
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean resteasyServletRegistratio() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean();
    registration.setServlet(new HttpServletDispatcher());
    registration.addUrlMappings("/*");
    return registration;
}


    @Bean
    public SpringBeanProcessorServletAware springBeanProcessorServletAware() {

        SpringBeanProcessorServletAware springBeanProcessor = new SpringBeanProcessorServletAware();

        return springBeanProcessor;
    }
```

But it will throw Nullpoint exception. It seems like the **servletContext** is required to make SpringBeanProcessorServletAware work.

Then I try to inject **servletContext**. But the bean SpringBeanProcessorServletAware is being created before ServletContextInitializer finished.

How to make some bean created after ServletContextInitializer is finished?
Am I wrong in do the integration between Spring Boot and Resteasy.

Comment: Can you paste the complete code of web.xml file in WEB-INF directory?

Comment: @harshavmb since I use the Spring boot, I don't need web.xml

Comment: This question is a duplicated of this other one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720400/how-configure-spring-boot-app-to-continue-to-use-resteasy/39114485#39114485